# How to add multiple drop down lists into a sql database the user desides

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql-server

Okay so I'm busy with a Questionnaire website and the client needs to  be able to create his own questionnaire. So my question is how do I insert 1+ dropdown lists into a table. Without knowing how much he will be using. For instance

He has a dropdown -> Country (with 5+ values)
and another dropdown -> Car (with 5+ values)

I need to save his questionnaire into database (if he wants to edit it later on) how would I work with the dropdown lists. Not looking for code, just a better logical reason of how and why.

Comment: you want to save every item in the database?

Comment: uhmmm..Preferably. But if there is a better way of doing it then ill take that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of project can range from fairly simple to very complicated.  From your simple description I would go with two tables.  Questions and answers with a questionID in the answer table.  You can then drive the dropdown box with this questionID.

Comment: I was thinking I have Main table with dropdown_FK then a dropdown table with Entities_FK then a Entity table. Going from single>many then single to many. Allowing me to have multiple "boxes" per questionnaire and multiple entries per "box"?